# How to make the connection between the broker and an external network?

Tags: mosquitto

I’m new in this field and I’m trying to create a device using arduino WiFi Rev 2 and the broker mqtt Mosquitto on an external network.

I’ve already installed Mosquitto on my PC and started it by the prompt. I changed the configuration file of Mosquitto in order to allow the listener on port 1883 and then run on prompt the command `mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf -v` and it worked.

But when I run `netstat-a` on the prompt, the port 1883 doesn’t appear on the address of the external network. What can I do to fix it ?

There’s the conf file I added

```
per_listener_settings true
listener 1883
protocol mqtt 
allow_anonymous true
listener 8083
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous true
```

Thanks for the your attention, hope to find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

With the configuration you have provided, mosquitto will bind to ALL addresses, this will be signified by it binding to `0.0.0.0:1883` (and `0.0.0.0:8083`)

So there is nothing to fix. Assuming no firewall/NAT between the Arduino and the machine running the broker it should just connect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Even if the conf file is right, when I open the prompt there’s no port 1883 on the address of the my external router. 
So when I upload the sketch of the IDE on the board Arduino WiFi Rev 2, the connection between the board and the broker fails.

Comment: How to setup port forwarding on your router is not a question for Stack Overflow (it's more of a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) question)

Comment: And what your describing is the NAT I mentioned, which was not included in the original question